# How to resolve Refused to set unsafe header "user agent" when using open-ai API

Tags: reactjs, openai-api

Im trying to use the chatGPT API to create a simple chat app. here is the source code.

```
import { Configuration, OpenAIApi } from "openai";

const openai = new OpenAIApi(
  new Configuration({
    apiKey: process.env.REACT_APP_OPEN_AI_SECRET_KEY,
  })
);

export const getChatGPTMessage = async (text: string): Promise<string> => {
  return await openai
    .createChatCompletion({
      model: "gpt-3.5-turbo",
      messages: [
        {
          role: "user",
          content: `${text}`,
        },
      ],
    })
    .then((res) => res.data.choices[0].message as unknown as string);
};
```

Everything seemed to work in the online tutorial I watched but I keep getting this error `xhr.js:162 Refused to set unsafe header "User-Agent"` Online search led me to believe that I should use Axios, but I don't control the actual request and I believe the OpenAI library already uses Axios. How can I solve this error?

It is also worth noting that I get also some weird `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 429 ()`  suggesting I have a problem with my OpenAI API key but i verified the Api key is set up correctly which poses another question. Is the API KEY the same as the secret key or are they different and if so, where can I find the correct API key?

Comment: Did you solve it? I looked all replies here but nothing have works

Comment: @DiegoVenâncio apparently you shouldnt call the OpenAI api from the frontend code. Only the backend. I think its for security purposes